# Could basic authentication affect Window.postMessage?

Tags: javascript, postmessage

When implementing communication between parent and iframe with JavaScript and [Windows.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) I see different behavior when basic authentication is turned on/off (same server different ports). I have no control over the iframe content so I don't know all details and cannot debug it. 
Could basic authentication affect a message sent with postMessage? When testing it all works fine in Firefox but in Chrome it only works when basic authentication is turned off. I know that question is a bit vague but maybe someone has an idea anyway.

Comment: postMessage is there to enable communication between the parent window and the iframe. If the iframe is not something you have control over it has no use. Basic authentication should not have anything todo with it.

Comment: What I meant with having no control over the content is that someone else is implementing it and that we have agreed on what messages to send.